# Script runs from command line, but not from finder

Tags: bash, macos

I have a bash script that runs my Go program. That's all it does, and when I run it from the command line, it works fine.

But when I run it by double clicking on it in Finder, it returns
`/Users/colin/go/metgen/metaphorgenerator.sh: line 2: ./binary: No such file or directory`

So I made it echo it's working directory, and it just prints `/Users/colin`, my home directory.

How do I get it to run the code from the directory the file is in? (I want it to work no matter what directory it's in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$0` is the full program name.  So you can get the directory with `HERE=$(dirname "$0")`.

Then, line 2 should have `${HERE}/binary`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point it to the location of the executable, either with a relative path from the working directory as in `go/metgen/binary`, absolute path like `/Users/colin/go/metgen/binary`, or [absolute path based on the parent executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/96588) (unfortunately [not reliable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).